# What's the difference between "real" and "imaginary" parts of a complex numer in Go?

Tags: go, numbers, complextype

I was reading Go's documentation for the [complex128](https://godoc.org/builtin#complex128) and [complex64](https://godoc.org/builtin#complex64) data types when I came across something odd:

> *"complex128 is the set of all complex numbers with float64 real and imaginary parts."*

And:

> *"complex64 is the set of all complex numbers with float32 real and imaginary parts."*

More specifically:

> *"real and imaginary parts."*

What's meant by this? How can a number be *"real"* or *"imaginary"*?

Comment: In mathematics there are a _lot_ of number systems. You might be familiar with natural numbers (0, 1, 2, 3, ...), whole numbers or integers (..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...), fractions, rationals (1/2, 7/9, -3/6), real numbers (3.14159, 7.2333...). Each system allows more calculations, e.g. you cannot dived 7 by 3 in the integers, but you can with fractions. Some things still cannot be done in reals (float64) like finding a x with `x*x == -1`.

Comment: This is why there are more elaborate number systems like the complex numbers or quaternions. Complex numbers are kinda pair of two real numbers, one is named the real part and the other is named the imaginary part of the complex numbers. These are defined technical _names_ (call them Hans and Horst if you get confused by real and imaginary). Do not think of an imaginary number as a real which is imaginary in the every day speed. This "imaginary" has a technical meaning and that meaning only. Google complex numbers or consult your school books for more details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is missing a basic understanding of what complex numbers are - this is a topic of math and not of software development. See [Wikipedia: Complex Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) for more information.

Comment: [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you don't know what complex, real, or imaginary numbers are, don't use those types. You don't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't dedicated to GoLang, to be honest.

Complex numbers are a mathematical concept.

Here is an example:

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "math/cmplx"
)
func main() {
  fmt.Println(cmplx.Sqrt(-1))
}
```

Expected output:

```
(0+1i)
```

There is a package named "cmplx" to work with complex numbers. So Sqrt of cmplx is similar to math one, but it returns a complex number instead.

As you see, and output consists of `0` and `1i`, and the last one is an imaginary part as we are not able to get a square root of `"-1"`.

Answer (score 1):

For complex numbers, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

The only Go-specific topic is that the "complex" types are built-in in Go, so unlike in other languages you can perform basic operations on them without importing additional packages:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  c1 := 1i
  c2 := 2 + 3i
  fmt.Println(c1 * c1) // i^2 = -1
  fmt.Println(c1 + c2) // i + (2+3i) = 2+4i
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VYUkRSLSct2).

For more advanced operations, you can use the `math/cmplx` package, similar to the `math` package for real numbers (as in being of habits' answer).